# jQuery popup box with options

Tags: jquery, popupwindow

I looked around on the web and this site, but can't seem to find an answer to my particular question.

I want to make a jQuery popup box that displays two options after someone clicks on a photo. "Showtimes" & "Trailer" If they click "Showtimes" it's an obvious link that takes to the corresponding page. The trouble I'm having is if they click the "Trailer" I want the popup box to turn into a trailer of the movie. aka just a embedded trailer from YouTube.

I just don't know how to make the popup box transform into the trailer with the button press.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of any significant information, all I can really suggest is something like the following, which assumes something similar to the following HTML:

```
<div class="popupBox">
    <!-- other stuff -->
    <a href="#" class="trailer">trailer</a>
    <a href="#" class="showtimes">showtimes</a>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('div.popupBox').on('click', 'a.trailers', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.popupBox').empty().append(youtubeEmbedCode);
});
```